# Diagonalisabity of a matrix belonging to a finite subgroup of $GL_n$($\mathbb C$)

Tags: linear-algebra

G is a finite subgroup of $GL_n$($\mathbb C$). Prove that every element of G is diagonalisable.

If A $\in$ G, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^k$= $I$ because the Group is finite. How do I prove that A is diagonalisable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^k = I$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $k$th roots of unity. There is a theorem in linear algebra that when the *minimal* polynomial of a matrix over a field $F$ has all of its roots in $F$ and those roots are distinct, the matrix is diagonalizable. (A counterexample is the shear matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$, which has minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$, which has a double root and the matrix is not diagonalizable since its 1-eigenspace is only 1-dimensional.) For the matrix $A$ above, its minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^k-1$ and therefore the minimal polynomial has distinct roots in $\mathbf C$ and thus $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbf C$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the standard Weyl unitary trick. Take any dot product $<. >$  in $L=\mathbb{C}^n$. Define the new (Weyl) product $(u,v)=1/|G|\Sigma_{g,\in G} <gu, gv>$. By Weyl, it is again a dot product on $L$ and every element of $G$ is an isometry with respect to it. So with respect to this dot product every $g$ is a unitary matrix, whence diagonalizable.

Comment: Is it true for $\mathbb C$ always or only for the algebraic closure of Q?

Comment: I think it is true for algebraically closed subfields of complex numbers.

Comment: Not able to understand the full implication of the unitarizability trick. Does it mean non diagonalisable matrices can be diagonalised using this trick.

Comment: No, non-unitary matrices with respect to the usual dot product become unitary with respect to new dot product. That helps proving that they are diagonalizable. But they were diagonalizable all along. There is a Wikipedia page about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_trick

Comment: A better text about the Weyl trick and other facts on linear representations of finite groups  can be found here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/RepresentationTheory/2010-2011/Representation_Theory.pdf But the best book on the topic is Serre's "Linear representations of finite groups" https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9458-7

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your answer but it is high stuff.